# Better way to change the content of a monadic type than `map`

Tags: scala, monads

I often have the requirement that the output requires another type than my functions returns.

So the last instruction looks like

```
Future {
  destroyEngine() // returns Unit
}.map(_ => Done) // is there a better way
```

Is there a better function in **Scala** for example something like:

```
Future {
  destroyEngine()
}.use(Done)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `Future` provides such methods directly, but it should be easy enough to do this yourself:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Bla {
  implicit class FutureOps[T](val f: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def as[B](b: => B): Future[B] = f.map(_ => b)
  }

  case object Done

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val res = Future {
      Thread.sleep(1)
    }.as(Done)
  }
}
```

Other functional IO effect systems usually have this built in, like [ZIO](https://zio.dev/):

```
import zio.ZIO

object Bla extends zio.App {
  override def run(args: List[String]): ZIO[Bla.Environment, Nothing, Int] = {
    val res: ZIO[Any, Nothing, String] = ZIO.effectTotal(1).as("Goodbye")
    res.fold(_ => 1, _ => 0)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, from ZIO I got the idea:)